# dotnet returns error 132 with image dotnet/sdk:6.0.302-alpine3.16-arm32v7 on Raspberry 3B+

Tags: docker

I want to build a .NET application inside a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. `dotnet`  build or publish, and even `--version` returns error code 132.

`docker build -t consoletest .`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/5 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.302-alpine3.16-arm32v7 AS build
 ---> de9190893e15
Step 2/5 : RUN dotnet --version
 ---> Running in 71c0dc4f9595
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet --version' returned a non-zero code: 132
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.302-alpine3.16-arm32v7 AS build

RUN dotnet --version
```

**lscpu**

```
Architecture:        armv7l
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               4
Model name:          Cortex-A53
Stepping:            r0p4
CPU max MHz:         1400.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
BogoMIPS:            89.60
Flags:               half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I guess. I was not aware anymore that I set up the 3B+ with 32-bit Raspbian. After a re-installation with 64-bit Raspbian, Docker... this worked:

```
>docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine
/ # dotnet --version
6.0.302
```